# glDrawElements causes low FPS of Android Game

Tags: android, performance

I am testing one of Android Game , but it's fps is too less.
After profiling this game APP with gl_trace ,it has been observed that glDrawElemnts takes lots of time.

what should i do to reduce this ??

need Help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be caused by many different things related to general OpenGL performance. Are you drawing many vertices, or are you calling `glDrawElements` many times in each frame? Are you drawing blended shapes that cover a lot of the screen and overlap?

Comment: yes i have call glDrawElements many times, but that is necessity due to complex graphics. I have search somewhere that to reduce performance problem  of this function use VBO. because without VBO it has to copy all data to command buffer ,Hence mention to use VBO for vertex and index data ,But i Donot know how to implement VBO .Can any body any idea how can i do this ?